# Unhanndled IO Error on fileReference.save()

Tags: apache-flex, exception, filereference

I am using a filereference Object to export an excel file from my flex application. I am using fileReference.save() from Flash player 10.  I am getting an error if the file i am trying to save is already open. This error is not getting handled even if i put a try catch block. I have tried adding a listener with IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR. Still the error is happening.  This is the Error message i am getting -  "Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2038: File I/O Error."

Thanks in advance.
Manoj

Comment: please share the code. Handling IOErrorEvent should help in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is asynchronous error, you can't catch it with `try-catch` block. Add an event listener for `IOErrorEvent` event.
Also, we need some details to get the source of the problem.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I had removed the IOErrorEvent listener in the next line after fileReference.save() assuming it is synchronous.